# Lightswitch - Change dataitem's related property through code

Tags: visual-studio-lightswitch

this is the simplified example similar to my prolem. Suppose that you have 2 sql tables: Car and Owner

Table Car has foreign key IDOwner. Lightswitch data model has dataitems Car and Owner, and

dataitem Car has subobject Owner which is null by default. I want to set Onwer subobject through code and not by auto generated AutoCompleteBox or something similar. I wrote the code this way:

Owner ow = this.DataWorkspace.MyData.Owners.Where(x => x.IDOnwer = SOME_ID).First();
//at this point variable ow is regullary loaded not null object - I saw it in the debugger

this.CarDataItem.Owner = ow;

//at this point ow is still loaded not null object but this.CarDataItem.Owner is still null - //also checked in the debugger

My question is what's the proper way to change this type of dataitem's subobjects through code?

If I open screen designer and drag Owner property of CarDataItem on the screen, I will get AutoCompleteBox where I can select Owner subobject, but I don't want that. I want to do this

automatically throug code. Thank you very much in advance!

Comment: where do you write this code? I mean, what event is binded to this code?

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand why *CarDataItem* exists. I understand that you have a *Car* entity, & you have an *Owner* entity. Have you defined a relationship between them? In your case, seeing as you're not specifying that there MUST be an owner, your relationship would be 0..1-Many.

If you had that relationship added, the *Car* entity would get a navigation property called *Owner* (unless you changed the name). It would then be a simple matter of your code doing the following:

//this is preferable to the line that you had
Owner ow = this.DataWorkspace.MyData.Owners_SingleOrDefault(SOME_ID);

this.Car.Owner = ow;

Comment: Sorry, I have used wrog words to describe situation. Yes, I have Car and Owner entities (not dataitems) in the data source. Dataitem is concrete entity on the screen. There is relationship defineda and it is 0..1-Many. But the problem is when I set ow object and say this.Car.Owner = ow , this.Car.Owner is still null..

Comment: No problem, but I'm sorry, I don't know what else to say. That's how things work, & it's a technique that I use often. As danihp asked, where is your code being used? In what method, of what entity? Or in a screen? We're going to need more information before we'll be able to help any further.

Answer (score 0):

do you have a model layer and using data annotations e.g. EF code first, to set up associations?

here is a contrived msdn example
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff422034%28v=VS.91%29.aspx